# How to change the color of faces of sphere on intersection with another object in threejs

Tags: three.js

I want to change the color of all the faces of the sphere which can't be seen from the origin due to an obstacle. I used a raycaster but the colors are not sharp and makes color gradient. How to have sharp color faces and store the sphere face color array which can later be loaded directly using its color Array. [I have tried but achieved this](https://codepen.io/rhxdmuku-the-sasster/pen/MWLBqOr?editors=1111)
[image]

```
enter code here
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What is happening here:

- You see a gradient cause of vertex attributes interpolation.
- [image]
- There is an optimization inside [`THREE.BufferGeometry`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/BufferGeometry), to minimise the number of attributes passes called `indexing` by reusing attributes. So two adjacents triangle share the same color attribute on their adjacent side vertices.

```c
const indices = [
   0, 1, 2,
   2, 3, 0,
];
```

- You need to used non-indexed geometries so each triangle have unique vertices attributes, like here: [How to disable color interpolation when using vertexColors?](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-to-disable-color-interpolation-when-using-vertexcolors/29006)

### Update on vertices count

- You achieved non-indexed. But now you see that you are only updating one vertex at a time.
- That's why in some cases, it's full red and sometimes, it is gradient red/green. What you need, is to update the right group of 3 vertices each time. 3 colors (for 3 vertices of each triangle) define the color that will be interpotated.
- You need to grab the index of the first vertex of each triangle

```js
 let i2 = Math.floor(i / 3) * 3;
```

- You need to update 3 set of colors instead of one.

```js
   colorAttribute1[3 * i2] = 1;
   colorAttribute1[3 * i2 + 1] = 0;
   colorAttribute1[3 * i2 + 2] = 0;
   colorAttribute1[3 * i2 + 3] = 1;
   colorAttribute1[3 * i2 + 4] = 0;
   colorAttribute1[3 * i2 + 5] = 0;
   colorAttribute1[3 * i2 + 6] = 1;
   colorAttribute1[3 * i2 + 7] = 0;
   colorAttribute1[3 * i2 + 8] = 0;
```

Comment: Can you share some code for this, I have tried (link) but it still makes gradient.

Comment: Thanks, this really helped but at some points it still have some gradient

Comment: From your codepen, i can see that you went a step ahead, but you forgot to grab the right index (the first vertex of each triangle, a mutiple of `3`) `let i2 = Math.floor(i / 3) * 3;`, and use it instead of `i` (any integer) that can be any index of the triangle, meaning that on "none dividable" number by 3 you set red for three vertices dispatched on two different triangles, having in result green/red gradients.

Comment: The result seems to have sharp triangular edges, can I have straight edges.